# How to exit a python application using tkinter and multiple scripts

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multithreading

So Im stuck on this little problem I have with tkinter. I have created a gui that has two buttons. Button A is attached to a function that calls a python file which is a huge script that runs forever.

```
def startbot():
    subprocess.call("xxx.pyw",shell=True)
```

Button B is attached to a function called close which performs `root.quit()`

Anybody familiar with tkinter knows what I am about to say next in that when I click button A, tkinter freezes and I am not able to click Button B. I believe this is due to tkinter and something about threading however I am not very familiar with this topic and was wondering how can I fix this? Assuming I can fix this however I still have one more problem. If I am able to click button B will that just close tkinter or will it stop Button A's function and tkinter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I'd use [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Button
from subprocess import Popen

root = Tk()

def start():
    global process
    process = Popen("python /path/to/file")

def stop():
    # Uncomment this if you want the process to terminate along with the window
    # process.terminate()
    root.destroy()

Button(root, text="Start", command=start).grid()
Button(root, text="End", command=stop).grid()

root.mainloop()
```

When you press `Start`, the script launches without freezing the GUI.  Pressing `End` will destroy the window but keep the script running (unless you uncomment that line).